# Why strtok_r break string at '.'(peroid) instead of ',' (comma)?

Tags: c, strtok, pic32

I am using pic32(C32 compiler) ,32 bit architecture for my iot module where i am receiving data from
cloud than extract into my application.I am using this function (these are maximum details i can
provide).First 3 values extracted successfully,after 3rd value i have a dns address like
xyz.gcloudxyz.in ,here is the problem i have faced strtok_r split string at '.' peroid instead of ','
comma.

> This is my src buff data
>
> ```
>   866758041000000,2,DV1,xyz.gcloudxyz.in,1111,2222,3333,DV2,xyz.gcloudxyz.in,1234,1231,1212,
> ```

```
void SERVERGetConf(ubyte *src,DEVICE_CONF *dst)
{
    unsigned char *src_ptr = src;
    unsigned char *token   = 0,*rest_ptr;
    unsigned char  matched_string[2] = ",";
    unsigned char cCount,AvlbConf = dst->avilable_config;
    
    token = (unsigned char *) strtok_r(src_ptr,",",&rest_ptr);
    
    if(!memcmp(token,modem.imei,sizeof(token)))
    {
        token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr);
        dst->avilable_config = atoi(token);
        for(cCount = 0;cCount < dst->avilable_config;cCount++)
          {
             DATA_SERVER_CONFIG t_conf = {0};
             
             token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr);
             memcpy(t_conf.data.id, token,sizeof(token));

             token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr); //**At this line split at '.'** 
             memcpy(t_conf.data.domain, token,sizeof(token));  

             token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr);
             memcpy(t_conf.data.port[0], token,sizeof(token));

             token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr);
             memcpy(t_conf.data.port[1], token,sizeof(token));

             token                = strtok_r(NULL, matched_string,&rest_ptr);
             memcpy(t_conf.data.port[2], token,sizeof(token));
             dst->device[cCount].data = t_conf.data;
          }
        modem.flag.sendingconfigration      = 0;
        conf.flags.bits.config_updated      = 1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me try this @user3121023

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), meaning that the code you post should A) compile correctly, and B) demonstrate the problem. We can't see how your `t_conf` structure (?) and its fields are defined so we can't reproduce your problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's Working correctly sir thank you much @user3121023. i want to know why sizeof doing problem like this

Comment: These are maximum details i can provide , i already mentioned @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica

Comment: @user3121023 - please put that in as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Then close-as-dup.